# Is it possible to detect the number of local variables declared in a function?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

In a Python test fixture, is it possible to count how many local variables a function declares in its body?

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 2

Test.assertEqual(countLocals(foo), 2)
```

Alternatively, is there a way to see if a function declares any variables at all?

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 2

def bar():
    pass

Test.assertEqual(hasLocals(foo), True)
Test.assertEqual(hasLocals(bar), False)
```

The use case I'm thinking of has to do with validating user-submitted code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the associated code object accounts for all local names in the `co_nlocals` attribute:

```
foo.__code__.co_nlocals
```

Demo:

```
>>> def foo():
...     a = 1
...     b = 2
...
>>> foo.__code__.co_nlocals
2
```

See the [*Datamodel* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> *User-defined functions*
>
> *[...]*
>
> `__code__`   The code object representing the compiled function body.
>
> *Code objects*
>
> *[...]*
>
> Special read-only attributes: *[...]* `co_nlocals` is the number of local variables used by the function (including arguments); *[...]*

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate somewhat on @Martijn excellent answer, if you read the documentation for the [inspect — Inspect live objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module, you can see that it allows for introspection of a wealth of data, including (as @Martijn noted) in the `code` type, the following attributes:

```
co_names    tuple of names of local variables
co_nlocals  number of local variables
```